# Is there any tutorial where I can learn big jQuery projects or plugins?

Tags: jquery

I want to learn jQuery. I tried various books, but they only tell you about the basic functions and how to use them.

I want something like where a full fledged project of grid or table sorting, etc. is build in jQuery and then the writer tells how he build the complete application using jQuery rather than small simple selectors.

For example, I tried reading the code of the plugin [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/), and I learned many new concepts of how things are used in a practical way.

But there were many things which I could not understand why they used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand the basics of how jQuery works, and if you know JavaScript, then you can use it to build big projects, but, if you don't know JavaScript then any reading of jQuery books won't help you much.

If you are having a hard time understanding what is being done then you may need to spend more time learning JavaScript, as jQuery is just some utility functions, basically, to help hide issues about cross-browser concerns from developers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of online resources, sure, but i found [**jQuery in Action (2nd Edition)**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182323) 
to be a ridiculously good resource.

- All of the API is included
- Most of the API has code samples to go with it
- The book is logically grouped by topic
- With the table of contents/index you can find just about anything quickly
- Having a printed book there next to your computer when you're programming can really help

The book is such that you can do a front-cover-to-back-cover reading sort of thing -OR- you can use it more as a reference.  It works well for both.

*(To be clear I don't have any association with the author or publisher)*

Answer (score 0):

Best way to learn jQuery is to understand the [source](http://github.com/jquery/jquery). Spend 15-30 minutes every day looking it over. Try to grasp a new function every day (some may take a couple of days).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, once you have the basics down (I assume you do since you find books with basics unhelpful), it's time to start building something.  As long as you have a goal in mind, a "thing" to build, you will begin finding the places you are weak and the things you don't know.  Then hit up the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and hunt for answers, scour Google, and hit up StackOverflow for help.